# Azure Kubernetes Service Connection Cannot be Verified

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops

I am trying to add a new kubectl task for an Agent Job in Pipelines. When I pasted the kubectl configuration, I received this error:

```sh
The URL resolves to address "https://api.dev.mysite.com/api/v1/nodes", 
which is in a special purpose range that is not allowed in a Service Endpoint.
```

It seems very odd to me that a standard Kubernetes path would be blocked off. Is there a workaround for this?

The config file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: [random stuff here]
    server: https://api.dev.mysite.com
  name: dev.mysite.com
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: dev.mysite.com
    namespace: default
    user: dev.mysite.com
  name: dev.mysite.com
current-context: dev.mysite.com
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: dev.mysite.com
  user:
    client-certificate-data: [random stuff here]
    client-key-data: [random stuff here]
    password: [password here]
    username: [username here]
- name: dev.mysite.com-basic-auth
  user:
    password: [password here]
    username: [username here]
```

Comment: what does your service definition look like? what about your manifest, what does it look like?

Comment: @Rico all I have is the kubeconfig file. I've omitted any sensitive info.

Comment: looks like you don't have the right role permissions to access the AKS cluster. did you provision the cluster?

Comment: @Rico no, that makes sense though. If you put it as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I added the answer. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks this user:

```sh
- name: dev.mysite.com
  user:
    client-certificate-data: [random stuff here]
    client-key-data: [random stuff here]
    password: [password here]
    username: [username here]
```

doesn't have the required kube-apiserver/Kubernetes access to list/create nodes.